# NoClassDefFoundError exception is throwing

Tags: android

hi dears I am getting an error in logcat which is totally unknown to me please help me out for this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1012)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1074)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:126)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without knowing your code? Could you add the relevant part(s) please?

Comment: I am also facing same crash in Play Store dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.

Copy jar **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar** file from **appcompat_v7 library** and paste in Your project **libs** Folder.

Then Clean And Build Your project.

It Will Work For You.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the android.support.v7.app.AppCompat library in your project
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Steps;
import as android project
file > import > D:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

add it your project.

Comment: dear I added it but the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

add this to your modules build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
```